# Why does order of defining attributes for a dynamically created checkbox in jquery affect its value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamically-generated

I have this code in a js file:

```
function buildRolePicker() {
    var pnl = $("[id$='staffRoles']");
    $.each(roles["ContactGroupRoles"], function(iteration, item) {
        pnl.append(
                $(document.createElement("input")).attr({
                    id: 'cgr' + item['RoleId'],
                    name: 'cgroles',
                    value: item['RoleId'],
                    title: item['RoleName'],
                    type: 'checkbox'
                })
        );
        pnl.append(
                $(document.createElement('label')).attr({
                    'for': 'cgr' + item['RoleId']
                })
                .text(item['RoleName'])
        );
    });

    alert(document.forms[0].cgroles[8].value);
}
```

I was wasting some time in other sections of code trying to work out why a call to

```
alert(document.forms[0].cgroles[8].value);
```

was returning a value of "on" when it should be returning a long. It turns out the problem is the order in which the attributes are defined. If i change this:

```
            $(document.createElement("input")).attr({
                id: 'cgr' + item['RoleId'],
                name: 'cgroles',
                value: item['RoleId'],
                title: item['RoleName'],
                type: 'checkbox'
            })
```

to this:

```
                $(document.createElement("input")).attr({
                    type: 'checkbox',
                    id: 'cgr' + item['RoleId'],
                    name: 'cgroles',
                    value: item['RoleId'],
                    title: item['RoleName']
                })
```

everything works fine and I get my long value as expected when i:

```
alert(document.forms[0].cgroles[8].value);
```

My question is why?

Test Data:

```
var roles = {"ContactGroupRoles":[
    {"RoleId":1,"RoleName":"Pending"},
    {"RoleId":2,"RoleName":"CEO"},
    {"RoleId":3,"RoleName":"Financial Controller"},
    {"RoleId":4,"RoleName":"General Manager"},
    {"RoleId":5,"RoleName":"Production Manager"},
    {"RoleId":6,"RoleName":"Sales Manager"},
    {"RoleId":7,"RoleName":"Marketing Manager"},
    {"RoleId":8,"RoleName":"Sales Agent"},
    {"RoleId":9,"RoleName":"Customer Service"},
    {"RoleId":10,"RoleName":"Manager"}
  ]};
```

Comment: Just a thought, but check out lines 874 and 1384 in jquery-1.4.2 (development version so it's readable, of course). It seems like if there's no value set for a checkbox it defaults to receiving the value "on" -- maybe this is happening in your case? I know you set a value, but perhaps it's not considered a valid value for a checkbox...

Comment: Where and how is `roles["ContactGroupRoles"]` declared? Please post all associated code.

Comment: Hi as mentioned, simply changing the order of attribute declaration resolves the issue so its not a problem with the validity of the value. roles["ContactGroupRoles"] is a javascript object. I can alert(item['RoleId']) and always get a value. Thanks Faisal, at least now i know where it was getting its "on" value from. Clearly you have to define the type before setting the value. Seems kind of obvious but i just thought jquery would "sort it" and i dont remember reading this as a requirement anywhere. (I actually dragged the basis of this code off of another SO question). http://tiny.cc/stc2m

Comment: @rism - Is this in IE, or another browser?

Comment: Gah, now that ove actually read that other post, i see he was having a similiar problem. I think ive just worked out the answer to his question. lol. Its the order of declaration.

Comment: @rism - I'm only seeing this in IE and Opera...Firefox/Chrome are working, though only IE has the `type` exception, hmm.

Comment: @Nick - Chrome and FF also give me a value of "on" if i dont define the type of the input first. Seems kind of obvious that you should have too. Teach me to drag and drop code i guess. :)

Comment: @rism - Is your actual code different?  I'm doing a very simple test for this: http://jsfiddle.net/UAJ5q/3/ try it in both :)

Comment: @Nick -My actual code is what ive posted but that is dfifferent from what you're testing. I wonder if the .each loop changes the equation?

Comment: @rism - It might, I posted an answer below trying to demonstrate the issue a bit more plainly, it's all moot I guess, since the proper solution is to change the order, you just had be curious as to what's happening.  I *expected* this from IE due to how it handlers `<input>` type change, or rather doesn't...Opera surprised me though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that for whatever reason, IE (IE8 at least) and Opera don't retain the `value` attribute (though Chrome/Firefox do) through changing the `type`.  Here's a simplified test:

```
$(document.body).append(
    $("<input />").attr({
        value: 'Test',
        type: 'checkbox'
    })
);
alert($("input").val());
alert(document.body.innerHTML);
```

[You can try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/UAJ5q/5/)

IE8/Opera alerts:

- "on"
- `<input type="checkbox">`

Chrome/Firefox alerts:

- "Test"
- `<input type="checkbox" value="Test">`

I'm not sure why Opera in particular is behaving this way, but in any case...just attempting to better demonstrate the issue, the solution of course is to keep the `type` attribute first.  Perhaps a future jQuery release will process `type` first in the loop, though if the `<input>` was defined with any attributes earlier this still wouldn't do much good.

However, the `$("<input />", { value: 'Test', type: 'checkbox' });` format suffers the same problem, IMO this *should* be fixed.